# Does the following constrained system of linear equations have a solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, linear-programming

Does the following system of equations have a solution?

$$\begin{pmatrix}
n_{1}\\ 
n_{2}\\ 
n_{3}\\ 
n_{4}\\ 
n_{5}\\ 
n_{6}
\end{pmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0  & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &  0& 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 &0  & 0 & 0 &  0&  0& 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
 0& 0 & 0 & 1 &0  & 0 &  0& 1 & 0 &0 \\ 
 0& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &0 \\ 
0 &  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0& 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
a\\ 
b\\ 
c\\ 
d\\ 
e\\ 
f\\ 
g\\ 
h\\ 
z\\ 
j
\end{pmatrix}$$

with the following constrains $a+b= D_{1}$ and $c+d=D_{2}$.

Where $n_{1},n_{2},n_{3},n_{4},n_{5},n_{6},D_{1},D_{2}$ are known.

Comment: Hint: You can add the constraints as additional rows to the matrix an $(n_i)$ vectors.

Comment: Why are some scalars lowercase and others uppercase? Why don't you just augment the system and append two equations?

Comment: Just edited thank you!

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think I know what you are saying, to extend the $(n_{i})$ vector by adding at the bottom the values $D_{1},D_{2}$ and equivalently extending the matrix with two more rows with $1$ in order to be multiplied with the $a,b,c,d$?

Comment: Further, the matrices in the r.h.s. can't be multiplied, since the left matrix has 10 columns and the column matrix has 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular form of matrix makes the problem easy.

Let: $$H=\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0  & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &0  & 0 & 0 \\ 
 0& 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
 0& 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  0&  0&  0
\end{bmatrix}$$ be the left-most four columns of your matrix, then your matrix is: $$\begin{pmatrix}H&I_6\end{pmatrix}$$
where $I_6$ is the $6\times 6$ identity matrix. Then you want:

$$\begin{pmatrix}n_1\\\vdots\\n_6\end{pmatrix} =H\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}e\\\vdots\\j\end{pmatrix}$$

So given any $a,b,c,d$ you can get:
$$\begin{pmatrix}e\\\vdots\\j\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}n_1\\\vdots\\n_6\end{pmatrix} -H\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{pmatrix} $$

So, given any $a,c$ you can solve for the rest of the variables uniquely as $b=D_1-a,d=D_2-c$ and:

$$\begin{pmatrix}e\\\vdots\\j\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}n_1\\\vdots\\n_6\end{pmatrix} -H\begin{pmatrix}a\\D_1-a\\c\\D_2-c\end{pmatrix} $$

So $$\begin{align}e&=n_1-a-c,\\ f&=n_2-D_1+a, \\g&=n_3,\\h&=n_4-D_2+c,\\z&=
n_5,\\j&=n_6.\end{align}$$

---

In general, if the equation is of the form: $$\mathbf n=\begin{pmatrix}H&I_n\end{pmatrix}\mathbf v$$
we can take this approach.  If $H$ is $n\times k$, write $\mathbf v=\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf u\\\mathbf w\end{pmatrix}$ where $\mathbf u$ is a $k$-vector of variables and $\mathbf w$ is a $n$-vector of variables.

Then given any $\mathbf u\in\mathbb R^k,$ we get a unique solution $$\mathbf w=\mathbf n-H\mathbf u$$

Or: $$\mathbf v=\begin{pmatrix}I_k&0\\-H&I_n\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf u\\\mathbf n\end{pmatrix}$$
Additional constraints on $\mathbf v$ can be seen as constraints on $\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf u\\\mathbf n\end{pmatrix}.$